# Is it safe to use multiple SQLiteDatabases and SQLiteOpenHelpers in one Android project?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-library

I have my android project (projectA) which I have to join with other 3rd party project (projectB) with minimal changes to both. I figured the nice way to do it would be to convert projectA to a library and make projectB use that lib.

The problem is the both projects use SQLite databases. They have their own SQLiteOpenHelpers and stuff, in short they both are written the normal way an android app that uses DB is written (their DATABASE_NAMES are different of course).

I wonder if there may be a potential of some conflict in this scenario? I don't know, some database deadlocks, hard to debug crashes etc? I'm a little worried because I saw this exception yesterday:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: 
    SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/[com.package.url.of.projectB]/databases/[projectAdatabaseName]
```

This may be related just to some bug in projectA, but I want to be sure that it is not caused by some confilct between the databases and that this kind of scenario I'm describing is acceptable. What are the potential pitfalls, things to watch for, best practices when joining two android projects with separate databases?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly safe to create and use multiple SQLiteOpenHelper as long as they are not using the same database, of course. But SQLiteOpenHelper is an abstract class and concrete implementations can introduce conflicts.

Comment: how can these concrete implementations conflict? What to watch for?